# Authoring tool for interactive documentations

Tags: technical-writing, tools

I am searching for an application (Desktop- or Web-App) to write and create interactive documentation (especially technical documentation).
I like Madcap Flare for technical writing, but I'm looking for something that can also create dynamic media - fulltext search, slideshows, expandables, and similar.

It should be easy to adapt and easy to integrate in other processes. And the important thing is that it needs to have a responsive HTML5 output.

If you are reading this and maybe working in the technical documentation sector, what program/app would you use for it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by interactive documentation, and what Flare doesn't provide that you need?  Thanks.  (I use Flare to produce HTML documentation with search and inline "pop-ups", but haven't done anything with embedded slideshows or videos.

Comment: Well Flare is great for text-only output with a simple navigation and search. However as you already mentioned Flare doesn't provide any interactive widgets like slideshows, videos, expandables, ... I am searching a tool that is like Flare (because it's great for technical writers) but with the ability of embedding interactive elements. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've made a small edit to, I hope, clarify (at least for my own initial confusion).  I hope we can find a tool for you!

Comment: I do not know why this is so extravagant. Actually this should be a trivial requirement at the present time.

Answer (score 3):

You can create responsive HTML5 outputs that have interactive elements, like slideshows, using native MadCap Flare functionality AND you can extend Flare's native functionality by incorporating a pre-coded, front-end framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

Here's some brief examples of how to accomplish what I think you are referring to above.

**Slideshows**

- See [Flare's webhelp](http://webhelp.madcapsoftware.com/flare11/Content/Home.htm) for an example of the kind of slideshow Flare supports natively.
- Bootstrap supports [carousels](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

**"Expandables"**

By this, I assume you mean text that you click on to reveal more text.

- Flare supports [drop-down text](http://webhelp.madcapsoftware.com/flare11/Content/Tutorials/Flare/TopNavigationAdv/HDYDT_DropDowns_TopNav.htm?Highlight=dropdown) for this need.
- Bootstrap supports [accordions](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion).

I have started to use Bootstrap with Flare, and I'm pretty sure that's what I'm going to do from now on. This method allows you to have a modern front-end with the beautiful content reuse of Flare.

If I were you, I'd get a trial version of Flare and try plugging in Bootstrap. See how you like it. PM if you need specific guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out relayto.com. Pulls in any kind of content in one place files/docs, links, images, videos and about 250 web services and then gives you ability to publish as a web page, PDF or microsite.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is not what can help me and what fits my requirements. 1. It has no HTML5 output - it is simply a web page from relayto.com that shows the content. I need a generated HTML page and that is why it is 2. not possible to integrate it in other processes. On top this doesn't provide the normal editor features like lists, bold or italic fonts and custom themes, etc.